# Accessing file raises change event

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I have two applications having reference to same xml file. One writes to the file, other monitors changes to the file.

In Application 1, I have used FileSystemWatcher to monitor changes, applied filter as LastWrite and watching for change event only. It runs continously in background

Application 2 reads a specific node in the file at startup and updates the node on users direction. Its a simple windows form, that reads a value from file when executed, and has the facility to change that value

Strange thing I came across when running both the applications, is that when application 2 starts up, file change event is raised in application 1 (Note: Application 1 continously watches the file)

I want to get rid of the change event raising in application 1 when application 2 starts up.

Is the filter incorrect or the Change event behaving nasty?

Comment: You detail that application 2 reads but has the facility to change that value.  What does that mean?  Does it mean you're opening the file with read/write permission?

Comment: Its a XML file. So using the XMLDocument Load method, I am loading it and then reading the appropriate node by using SelectSingleNode. I am not sure if that opens the file in a write mode.

Comment: hmmm, hard to tell.  You could try loading the file into a `MemoryStream` and using `XmlDocument.Load(Stream)` to see if the notifications go away.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx):

> The `Changed event` is raised when changes are made to the size, system
>   attributes, last write time, last access time, or security permissions
>   of a file or directory in the directory being monitored.

If Application 2 opens the file and the OS keeps track of last access times, a `Changed` event will be raised. Since there's no facility to filter only those events that actually write data to the file, you will have to determine what happened by keeping state on Application 1.

For example, now that you know what's going on you can keep a cache of the [last write time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) and decide to ignore the event if that hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But last write time doesnt seems to be reliable option. One thing that annoys me is that the operations on application2 are so quick i.e. the user opens application2 and changes the value immediately. This leads to two change events firing in a quick succession in Application 1. And thus application 1 gets an exception "Could not open the file because its being used by another process". I think I need a better locking method while reading the file.